# Quadratic polynomial with complex coefficients problem

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

> Find the roots for
>
> $$P(z)=z^2-(1+2i)z-\frac{3}{2}+2i$$

---

I can't get this to make sense. Here's what I've done so far:

$$D=b^2-4ac=(-(1+2i))^2-4\cdot1\cdot(-(\frac{3}{2}-2i)=3-4i$$
Since the discriminant is complex, I solve it as a binomial equation:
$$w^2=D=3-4i$$
$x^2-y^2=3$ and $2xy=-4$
$$2xy=-4\Rightarrow y=\frac{-2}{x}$$

I insert this in the first equation:

$$x^2-(\frac{-2}{x})^2=3\Rightarrow x^2-\frac{4}{x^2}=3$$
$$(x^2-\frac{4}{x^2})x^2=3x^2$$
$$x^4-3x^2-4=0$$

$x^2=u$:
$$u^2-3u-4=0$$

$$D=(-3)^2-4\cdot(-4)=25$$

Finding $u$:

$$u=\frac{3±\sqrt{25}}{2}=4 \lor -1$$

I'll go with 4 as $x$ and $y$ need to be real:

$$x^2=u=4\Rightarrow x_1=2 \lor x_2=-2$$

Now I need to find the $y'$s:

$$2xy=-4\Rightarrow y_1=-1 \lor y_2=1$$

The roots are therefore $z_1=2-i$ and $z_2=-2+i$. Which is wrong, it should've been $z_1=\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}i$ and $z_2=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{2}i$. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the quadratic formula $$z=\frac{1+2i\pm \sqrt{(-(1+2i))^2-4(-\frac{3}{2}+2i)}}{2}=\frac{1+2i\pm \sqrt{-3+4i+6-8i}}{2}=\frac{1+2i\pm \sqrt{3-4i}}{2}.$$ Now, $\sqrt{3-4i}$ could be either $2-i$ or $-2+i$. Substituting back in, we have $$z_1=\frac{1+2i+2-i}{2}=\frac{3+i}{2}=\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}i$$ and $$z_2=\frac{1+2i-2+i}{2}=\frac{-1+3i}{2}=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{2}i.$$

In your work, it appears that you have simply solved for the complex roots of $x^2=3-4i$, that is: $2-i$ and $-2+i$.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is the following:

$$z^2-(1+2i)z+-\frac{3}{2}+2i=0 \Rightarrow$$

$$z^2-(1+2i)z+(\frac{(1+2i)}{2})^2-(\frac{(1+2i)}{2})^2-\frac{3}{2}+2i=0\Rightarrow$$

$$(z-\frac{(1+2i)}{2})^2=\frac{3-4i}{4} \Rightarrow z=\frac{(1+2i)}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(3-4i)}$$

but,

$$(2-i)^2=(i-2)^2=3-4i \Rightarrow \sqrt{(3-4i)}=2+i \  or  \ i-2.$$

Thus,

$$z=\frac{(1+2i)}{2}+\frac{1}{2}(2-i)=\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}i$$
 or

$$z=\frac{(1+2i)}{2}+\frac{1}{2}(i-2)=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3}{2}i.$$